# @EventHandler retry logic and DistributedCommandBus setup

Tags: spring-boot, axon

1st Question:
So I am using Spring Eureka and the `DistributedCommandBus` set via the following:

```java
  public CommandRouter springCloudCommandRouter(DiscoveryClient discoveryClient, Registration localServiceInstance) { ... }
  public CommandBusConnector springHttpCommandBusConnector(@Qualifier("localSegment") CommandBus localSegment, RestOperations restOperations, Serializer serializer) { .. }
  public DistributedCommandBus springCloudDistributedCommandBus(CommandRouter commandRouter, CommandBusConnector commandBusConnector) { ... }
```

and my question for this part is how can i show that this is working? I have two K8 pods running the above code and have seen one run the `@CommandHandler` and the other run the `@EventSourcingEvent` but did not see anything in the logs to give any indication that it is using the bus.

Just want to be able to show that it is "working" as i have been asked to do so.

the Eureka part is working and i see all the info from said dashboard.

---

Edit - removed 2nd question to ask in another thread

Comment: I believe you should split this up in to two distinct questions. From StackOverflow's perspective that's more helpful for people which experience the same issue. It keeps both the question and the answer more concise.

Comment: understood. and i can do that as i might have resolved the 2nd part of the question by trial and error.

Comment: Good stuff, thanks for the edit @sherring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep focus with my answer, I'll only provide a suggestion for your first question, which summarizes to:

> How can I point out my `DistributedCommandBus` set up with Eureka is actually routing the commands to different instances?

I would suggest to set up some logging around this.
That way, you could log when the message is dispatched from Node 1 and when it is handled by Node 2.
Ideal for this would be to register the `LoggingInterceptor` as a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` **and** `MessageDispatchInterceptor`.

To do so, you will have to register it on the `DistributedCommandBus`, but also on the "local segment" `CommandBus`. The `DistributedCommandBus` will be in charge of dispatching it and thus calling the `LoggingInterceptor` upon dispatching. The local segment/`CommandBus` is in charge of providing the command to a Command Handler in the right JVM and as such will call the `LoggingInterceptor` upon handling.

The sole downside to this, is that the `LoggingInterceptor` will be a handler and dispatch interceptor as off Axon Framework release 4.2.
Thus, for now, you will have to do with it only being a Handler Interceptor.

However, this would suffice as well, as the `LoggingInterceptor` will only log upon handling the command.
This would then only occur on the Node which actually handles the command.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That did help and i was able to see the logging on various JVMs running behind Spring Eureka.

one thing i did notice (an maybe i missed it in the docs) that i did have to use the following to get the Eureka part working:

```
@Bean(name = "localSegment")
public CommandBus configureCommandBus() 
```
else spring fails on not able to find localSegment bean

Comment: I would assume that in an auto configure environment that you shouldn't have to  specify the `localSegment` forcefully. So, that you had to seems kinda interesting. If you want you could file this as an issue on the framework's repository, together with a sample project showing what's failing. That might give a good handle to figure out what's what.